# Telerik MVC model returns NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

The model that I bind to Telerik grid is NULL in the post method of the controller.

```
@model Empyrean.SafeHarbor.Web.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel

 Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.DataFiles)
    .Name("DataFiles")
```

this is how I get it from controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Dashboard(DashboardViewModel dashboardModel)
    {
dashboardModel.DataFiles
}
```

another additional information is that I'm doing form.submit on dropdownlist's onchange event that is triggering the post action.

Comment: I don't understand.  The second code snippet doesn't even compile.

Comment: It's just for representational purpose, dont use it literally. Let me know what other details you need.

Comment: Are you expecting all of the items in the grid to POST? The Telerik grid does not do that.

Comment: So, are you saying that the only way I can persist the model is by using session?